# Amazon RDS not able to connect to Node JS API hosted on Render

Tags: node.js, networking, amazon-rds

I have set up my Amazon RDS database and configured my personal IP successfully to connect to the API running on localhost. However, when attempting to connect the database to the API hosted on Render, I encounter a connection timeout error.

Steps taken:

Ensured DB status is available
Added the IP address of my Render-hosted API server to the database configuration
Noteworthy details:

API server is hosted in the us-central network zone
Database is in the ap-south-1 network zone
Seeking insights on resolving this connectivity issue between the Render-hosted API and the Amazon RDS database.